# Is this problem wrongly built? Or is there a solution which I don't know how to arrive at?

Tags: inequality

I was solving a Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality based problem. Given that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ I am supposed to show that $x+y+z \le 6$. After struggling for a while I realised that I could solve this inequality had the condition been $x^2+y^2+z^2=12$. This was my solution:
$(x.1+y.1+z.1)^2 \le (x^2+y^2+z^2)(1^2+1^2+1^2)$

$\implies (x+y+z)^2 \le 12*3$

$\implies (x+y+z)^2 \le 12*3 \le 36$

Taking square root on both sides, I got

$(x+y+z) \le 6$

Now I am wondering whether I detected a typo in the problem ($x^2+y^2+z^2=12$, not $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$) or is there a real way to reach $(x+y+z) \le 6$ starting from $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ based on Cauchy-Schwarz principles!

The main reason for this doubt is I am stuck on an extension of this problem in which I need to prove $x^3+y^3+z^3 \ge 24$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Showing $x+y+z\leq 6$ is straightforward from $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1\Rightarrow |x|,|y|,|z|\leq 1\Rightarrow x+y+z\leq 3<6.$$ But this wouldn't work for your extension, so I guess there is something wrong in the question.

Comment: Well, Cauchy-Schwarz gives you $(x+y+z)^2 \leqslant (x^2+y^2+z^2)\cdot(1^2+1^2+1^2) = 1\cdot 3 = 3$, so $\lvert x+y+z\rvert \leqslant \sqrt{3} < 6$.

Comment: It goes perfect with GS too: $(x+y+z)^2 \le (x^2+y^2+z^2)(1+1+1)\le 1\cdot 3\le 36$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part of your problem, assuming $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ is actually no problem, because $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ implies $x,y,z\le 1$, so $x+y+z\le 3<6$. 
Also, using Cauchy-Schwarz you can slightly improve this bound to $x+y+z\le \sqrt{3}$.

Looking however also at your next problem, showing that $x^3+y^3+z^3\ge 24$, it seems that you are right. The assumption $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ does not imply this, because clearly $1^2+0^2+0^2=1$, but $1^3+0^3+0^3=1<24$.

Taking however, your modified assumption $x^2+y^2+z^2=12$ we obtain by Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$144=(x^\frac32 x^\frac12+y^\frac32 y^\frac12+z^\frac32 z^\frac12)^2 \le (x^3+y^3+z^3)(x+y+z)\le 6(x^3+y^3+z^3),$$

as required. Therefore, you are right in saying, that this is most likely a typo in the problem statement.

Comment: Exactly. If x, y and z are all <1 in the first case, how come their cubes be greater than 24!

Comment: I worked out as suggested and could prove $x^3+y^3+z^3 \ge 24$. Assuming that professors seldom ask new questions, I searched old University exam papers. I found this question in December 2007 term exam with the assumption that $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 12$!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no need for Cauchy inequality. Obviously $x\leq1$. (why?). Similarly $y$ and $z$ are. So $x+y+z\leq 3$. This inequality can be strengthen since x, y, z can't take value 1 at the same time.

Comment: I understand that x, y, and z must be less than 1. And hence their sum would be less than 6. But the problem insists using Cauchy-Schwarz. Besides, if sum of squares are less than one, sum of cubes can't be greater than 24.

Answer (score 0):

We have $x^2\le1$, and thus $x\le1$. Similarly, we have $x+y+z\le3<6$.

Comment: I know. Had the question not insisted on using Cauchy-Schwarz, I would have used this approach. Also if sum of squares are less than one, sum of cubes can't be greater than 24.